# SSL Certificate issue with using HTTP/2 as a communication mechanism inside LAN

Tags: ssl, nginx, electron, chromium, http2

We are running servers which run multiple processes each, who in turn currently communicate with each other using HTTP (Using 1-2 physical servers per client, and there are multiple clients with separate servers).

The servers are hosted locally per client.

We're thinking of migrating our `nginx` service, which is serving static files (multiple images, videos), to HTTP/2, in order to speed things up, as it is very common to request 1000 images at a time, which is an area where HTTP/2 excels.

For the client side we're using a chromium-based (`Electron`) client.

A problem arises from the above, where a TLS certificate is required when using `HTTP/2` in the version of chromium we're using. Since this is a LAN there's no domain name, and even the IP addresses are not guaranteed to be static.

note: Using TLS is just a bonus, our main goal is to get the latency improvement from `HTTP/2`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: How about using Host name on the client machines using host file?

Comment: I'm going to attempt a POC and see if this works. Will update here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to issue a self-signed certificate for a domain, which was added to the hosts file of all affected clients. The certificate authority was manually declared as trusted in all client machines.

For a more general solution, one could use a any DNS resolution option so long as it is consistent across for all clients, and any signed certificate, while a self-signed-signature would require a manual addition of the CA file to all the clients.